# How to get some ether in my local Geth account?

Tags: ethereum, truffle, geth

I have set up Geth and created some account with no balance in them. So I cannot make any transaction as it costs Gas fee. How to create account with some initial balance so that I can test my contracts.
I have created account using the following command:

```
    > personal.newAccount()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're running a [private network](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/private-network) and not connecting to an already existing public network (e.g. Ropsten, Rinkeby, Kovan, ...).

You can add the pre-funded accounts to your `genesis.json`, under the `alloc` property. Example from the linked documentation:

```
"alloc": {
    "7df9a875a174b3bc565e6424a0050ebc1b2d1d82": { "balance": "300000" },
    "f41c74c9ae680c1aa78f42e5647a62f353b7bdde": { "balance": "400000" }
}
```

These accounts will be funded in the first block, so you'll need to re-init your network in order to fund the accounts.

---

If you want to fund your accounts on a public network, you can't just re-init the whole public network. But there are so called **faucets** for testnet networks, that give you some small amount of testnet ETH. Example: https://faucet.metamask.io/ (requires MetaMask wallet extension to be installed in your browser).